# Effective resultset structure in case of Inner Join on more than two tables

Tags: sql, database, join, resultset

I was going through [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/purcell/0112purcell.html#leftoj) to see how the effective resultset looks like if we join (Inner/Outer) two tables.

I was just curious to know how the resultset looks like, If we perform Inner/Outer join on more than two tables?

Let's say I've three tables:

```
 1. USERS
 2. ADDRESS (Store User's address contains Foreign Key USERS.USER_ID)
 3. ITEMS (Contains Items that user sold contains foreign key USERS.USER_ID)
```

Now If I write a SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM USERS users INNER JOIN ADDRESS address ON users.USER_ID = address.USER_ID
                            INNER JOIN ITEMS items ON users.USER_ID = items.USER_ID WHERE....
```

How the effective resultset will look like? Whether the DB creates two separate resultset pertaining to each JOIN condition or there will be a single resultset combining all the JOINS? When I say ResultSet,  i mean how the effective DB structure looks like (as in the link I've mentioned on top).

Answer (score 0):

Lets me Tell you brief description of the Inner Join And Outer Join.
Simply join is for to view columns from two or more tables together.

Inner Join :- The Matched rows Of the Two or more Tables

SELECT ... FROM USERS users INNER JOIN ADDRESS address ON users.USER_ID = address.USER_ID
                            INNER JOIN ITEMS items ON users.USER_ID = items.USER_ID WHERE....

What this Statement says is "SELECT ... FROM USERS users INNER JOIN ADDRESS address ON users.USER_ID = address.USER_ID"  gives some rows with the filter specified.

INNER JOIN ITEMS items ON users.USER_ID = items.USER_ID WHERE.... :- statement adds columns of the table [ITEMS] with the specified criteria "users.USER_ID = items.USER_ID"

Outer Join :- Different Row of the table mean no rows matched in table.

Two type of the Outer Join
  Right Outer :- Not Matched row of the right side table
  Left Outer :-Not Matched row of the right side table

Comment: Thanks. I know this. What I'm trying to figure out is effective structure when we join more than 2 tables by Inner/Outer Join?

Comment: I think it depends on the situation.